# Kubernetes log location in pod

Tags: logging, kubernetes

I am just trying to find the log location in the pod.

I just logged into the pod as below.

```
kubectl exec -it POD_NAME bash
```

But, the logs are not available under `/var/logs`. Not sure what is the actual log location and how to change that.

Comment: are you looking for logs from application or kubernetes?

Answer (score 26):

If your application is writing logs to file, then the location of that log file within the container depends on your application. The location of the log file on the host depends on whether you've mounted the log directory on the host.

---

If your application is writing logs to `stdout`, then your container runtime would capture each line and store it on the host. For Docker, this is stored in the `/var/lib/docker/containers` directory.

But Kubernetes also makes it easier for you to find the log files on the Kubernetes node, by symlinking the relevant log file to `/var/log/pods/<namespace>_<pod_name>_<pod_id>/<container_name>/`.

Answer (score 6):

It's impossible to answer your question, because no one other than you knows how your application configured and deployed.

I can only guess your application writes logs to `stdout` via `Docker` json logging driver and your logs are stored on the one of your k8s nodes:

```
$ sudo find /var/lib/docker/containers -name "*-json.log"
```

By default you can find pod's logs with `kubectl -n <namespace> logs <pod_name>` command

More info: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/

Answer (score 1):

The log file in your containers depend on the application you are running, different applications output logs to different location, for instance, the tomcat in my environment output logs into /usr/local/tomcat/logs directory.

The logs of pod, we mean console output here, will be saved into a container directory in your host, then linked to /var/log/pods/$pod_name directory, you can find logs there.

Comment: Mine is a Spring boot application with Jetty server and log file is not available in both of the above locations.

Comment: you should check the log configure to find out the log directory, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

Please check /opt/logs/app.log

If you are unable to find this directory then just search app.log using find command.

```
 find / -name "app.log"
```

In worst case

```
find / -name "*.log"
```