# Java console vs RollingRandomAccessFile logging

Tags: java, logging, log4j2, fileappender

1. What is the difference between console and File based logging from performance standpoint?
2. In the case of file based logging I Understand that logging performance is impacted by disk io. Will the similar constrain hold true in console based logging?
3. Where are the logs buffered till they are flushed to console?
4. <strike>In the case of kubernates how does it let me download console logs? Where is it stored actually ?</strike>(answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58922141/3892213))
5. If i am using [async logger](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/performance.html#asyncLoggingResponseTime), are [these](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/performance.html#tradeoffs) perf benchmark still relevant to me?

Comment: There are some [old benchmarks](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/performance.html#whichAppender) on Log4j's site, but I have serious doubts on the performance of the console appender (should be on par with the `FileAppender`).

Comment: will it matter if we are using async logger?